# Python numpy array assign values to each column according to row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to assign row-specific values to each row in a 2D numpy array. In particular, each row should contain the value of the reciprocal of its row number. In other words, all columns in row 1 should have values 1, all columns in row 2 should be 1/2, all in row 3 should be 1/3, and so on.
I tried this:

```
m = 3
n = 10

train = np.empty([n,m], float)

for curr_n in range(n):
    train[curr_n,:] = 1/(curr_n+1)

print train
```

But the output is:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

What am I doing wrong? I used "float" at the beginning, but I'm still getting solid 0 integers for all but the first row.

Comment: you need 1. to convert it to a float.

Comment: [np.true_divide](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.true_divide.html)

Comment: `1/(curr_n+1)` always return 1 or 0 because `curr_n` is a type of integer. You might want to do like `1.0/(curr_n+1)` or `1/float(curr_n+1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implicit type conversion has been added in Python 3, so your original code will then work, as is:

```
from __future__ import division

m = 3
n = 10

train = np.empty([n,m], float)

for curr_n in range(n):
   train[curr_n,:] = 1/(curr_n+1)

print train
```

Some information on the `__future__` module can be seen in the official docs [future module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html)

Or, as sshashank124 put in his answer and I put in the comment, you can use 1. or 1.0 to force float behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You have a simple `type` problem. Use `1.0` instead of `1` in your reciprocation. The following works:

```
m = 3
n = 10

train = np.empty([n,m])

for curr_n in range(n):
    train[curr_n,:] = 1.0/(curr_n+1)   #converted 1 to 1.0

print train
```

### Explanation

Although you might think that numpy deals with floats by default, in this case, the numpy array is getting assigned the value **after** python has had the time to calculate the inverses. It is then that `python` truncates your floats to an int and numpy innocently converts that sneaky `int` to a `float` just as it is supposed to and ends up taking **all the blame**.